# How to start other services from one service in microservices using spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm having different micro-services such as configuration service, service registry, order service, customer service, payment service, front-end service, these services they fetch their configurations from config server and they are all connected to service registry, my question is, is it possible to start all micro-services from one service for-example if I'm to start service registry should be able to start all other services.

Note, I have created each service as a separate project

Comment: idea could  compose application  via create  ```compound``` ,if your are in deploy environment  you can use shell script  , docker-compose , gitlab,github action to  customlized start order

Comment: Thank you @Peng for your response, If I'm to use docker-compose can I use it in development environment or it's necessary to be in production environment

Comment: all above just is tools , whatever develop or production is ok . and i  have mistake above  ,
just use docker-compose , dev and  production  both is ok

Comment: I'm interested with docker-compose and I have never used it before so should I create the file docker compose in each application or it has to be in one service that will be used to call other services

Comment: in general  , you should define a dockfile for every service , build the service images and then  use docker-compose to compose them. here is a link for sample project ,  just for reference .

Comment: [github link](https://github.com/pengpengno/Meeting/tree/main/meeting-gui)